# What is the best approach to creating a publication quality table in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would like to create a publication quality textual table in Mathematica 8.  Is there a way to create and format a nice table similar to tables that you can create in MS Word in Mathematica?

This table would be a part of the text - not used for matrix operations.

Comment: Please include an image of the kind of output you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what format your data takes it's difficult to offer a structured code, but presuming that it's tables of results, then once you have your data then you can use the Grid function, there is an interesting example in the standard help documentation, where the code below is taken from that might get you started.

```
Grid[data, Alignment -> Left, Spacings -> {2, 1}, Frame -> All, 
 ItemStyle -> "Text", Background -> {{Gray, None}, {LightGray, None}}]
```

Where 'data' is clearly going to be your own data, this gives a nice presentable table as in the link [in the official documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/EnterRangesAndOptionsForFunctions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since you question is at present extremely general here is an equally general answer.

[`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Grid.html), its [options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Grid.html#1519354290), and related functions such as [`Item`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Item.html) allow quite a range of style and formatting options in a table.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in my [`SciForm` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9015/280) which, for example, [allows](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9015/280) to produce the following table:

[image]